# How to convert this SQL Select query to perform an update on a table value for the result set?

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, magento2

The below query correctly gives me a list of Enabled Configurable items, where ALL associated simple items are disabled.  How can I amend this to update the 'status' attribute value to '2' for the configurable items in this list.  (They have no child items so need to be disabled)

I appreciate I have mixed together approaches of table naming and referencing. I'm new to this and have combined elements of different solutions.

```
SELECT `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` FROM  (((`mgic_eav_attribute`
  join `mgic_catalog_product_entity_int` on ((`mgic_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = `mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`attribute_id`)))
  join `mgic_catalog_product_entity` on ((`mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`entity_id` = `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`)))
  join `mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item` on ((`mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`entity_id` = `mgic_cataloginventory_stock_item`.`product_id`)))
WHERE `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`type_id` = 'configurable' AND ((`mgic_eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` = 'status') and
  (`mgic_catalog_product_entity_int`.`value` = 2)) AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM mgic_catalog_product_super_link cpsl
    INNER JOIN mgic_catalog_product_entity_int cpei ON cpei.entity_id = cpsl.product_id
    WHERE 
      parent_id = `mgic_catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id`
      AND cpei.attribute_id = 97
      AND cpei.value = 1 
);
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fetch IDs of configurables with disabled simples

As `status` attribute will always have id 97 you could use the following SQL:

```
SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity` cpe
WHERE `type_id` = 'configurable' AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM catalog_product_super_link cpsl
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int cpei ON cpei.entity_id = cpsl.product_id
    WHERE 
      parent_id = cpe.entity_id
      AND cpei.attribute_id = 97
      AND cpei.value = 1
);
```

---

### Disable products by IDs

To answer your updated question I would suggest you fetching all entity ids and then just use Magento models to change status of each product like suggested here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152263/how-to-disable-enable-a-product-programatically-in-magento2 .
For example:

```
<?php
class Example
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Disable all products by IDs
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function disableProducts($productIds)
    {
        $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory()->create();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'))
            ->setPageSize(999);

        $productCollection->getSelect()
            ->where('NOT EXISTS(
                    SELECT *
                    FROM catalog_product_super_link cpsl
                    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_int cpei ON cpei.entity_id = cpsl.product_id
                    WHERE 
                      parent_id = e.entity_id
                      AND cpei.attribute_id = 97
                      AND cpei.value = 1
                )');
        foreach ($productCollection as $p) {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById(
                $p->getId(),
                true /* edit mode */,
                0 /* global store*/,
                true/* force reload*/
            );
            $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
            $this->productRepository->save($product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this, and it was super helpful.  I updated my question to get to the end result I'm after.  Can you help?

Comment: How do I specify the result set of the SQL query to be the basis of the obtained ProductIds?  Also, I am unfamiliar with this method, how do I initiate this function?

Comment: I updated my example. You can see that it uses Magento collection to select all configurable product and then iterates through the collection to disable each product.